# Preventing axis from updating on camera move - mayavi python

Tags: python, axis-labels, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I previously found a flag command to set that allowed me to prevent the axes of the scene from updating on camera move. Now I can't find it again. I've been digging through documentation but am not having any luck.

To further explain, I don't want the axes to update positioning as shown in these two images:

Before move:

[image: before move]

After move:

[image: after move]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand exactly what you need but maybe you can try:

```
axes.axes.fly_mode = 'none'
```

For example:

```
from mayavi import mlab

myfig  = mlab.figure()
myplot = mlab.plot3d([0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,1])
myaxes = mlab.axes()
myaxes.axes.fly_mode = 'none'

mlab.show()
```

Comment: What would you attach this to? This alone is not valid, and when I tried to attach it to other objects such as the figure I get an error `object has no attribute 'axes'`

Comment: I ran the example in this answer and it runs fine (though it may not solve your problem which is not very clear to me). What is the problem with it?

Comment: Got it, did not realize that I needed to generate a `mlab.axes` object to attach this to. Your expanded code does work and makes sense now. Thanks!